# The weak topology $\sigma(\mathscr M(S),\mathscr C_b(S))$ is not metrizable unless $ S$ is a finite set

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to follow the arguments in the following paragraphs.

[image]

I am having trouble with the 3 highlighted sentences. They contain facts that I am not familiar with and I couldn't find a proof or explanation of the first two, while for the third I would like to know if I filled out the details correctly.

1. If $\mathscr C_b( S)$ had a countable basis, it would be a union of countably
   many finite dimensional subspaces.
2. If $ S$  is infinite, finite dimensional subspaces of $\mathscr C_b( S)$  are closed sets with empty interior in the standard sup-norm
   topology of $\mathscr C_b( S)$ .

**Could you please prove ,point to a resource containing the proof or explain why they are true?**

3 "By the Baire category theorem [26, Theorem 2.5.2] $\mathscr C_b(S)$ cannot be a countable union of closed sets with empty interior."
This is the quoted theorem:

[image]

**I rewrote this part as I understand it, please tell me if it's correct:**

By points 1 and 2 I have:
$\mathscr C_b( S) = \cup_{i=1}^\infty W_i$ with $W_i$ a finite-dimensional subspace, which is a closed set with empty interior with respect to the sup-norm metric. Therefore since it's closed it's closure coincides with itself, and I have that $W_i$ is closed with empty interior, that is by definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) a nowhere dense subset of $\mathscr C_b( S)$, Taking complements:

$\emptyset= (\mathscr C_b( S))^C = (\cup_{i=1}^\infty W_i)^C$ is by the Baire category theory dense. (in $\mathscr C_b( S)$ I guess ).  But the empty set is not dense in a non-empty superset of it(correct?). I think this is why it says that "$\mathscr C_b( S)$ cannot be a countable union of closed sets with empty interior."